# Seq for fast random access and fast growth in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What would be the best Scala collection (in 2.8+), mutable or immutable, for the following scenario:

- Sequentially ordered, so I can access items by position (a Seq)
- Need to insert items frequently, so the collection must be able to grow without too much penalty
- Random access, frequently need to remove and insert items at arbitrary indexes in the collection

Currently I seem to be getting good performance with the mutable ArrayBuffer, but is there anything better? Is there an immutable alternative that would do as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to go thru this excellent collection API documentation by Martin Odersky and Lex Spoon: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/whatsnew/collections-api/collections.html

Comment: Thanks - I had missed that one somehow.

Answer (score 4):

Mutable: `ArrayBuffer`

Immutable: `Vector`

Answer (score 4):

If you insert items at random positions more than log(N)/N of the time that you access them, then you should probably use `immutable.TreeSet` as all operations are O(log(N)).  If you mostly do accesses or add to the (far) end, `ArrayBuffer` and `Vector` work well.

Answer (score 2):

`Vector`. `IndSeq` from [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) should be even better.

Comment: And Rope in the upcoming 5.1 release of Scalaz.

Comment: It should be (very) slightly worse at "frequently need to remove and insert items at arbitrary indexes".